# Add a single object to an array

Tags: jq

So I have this json structure:

```json
{
  "dog": [
    {
      "name": "sam",
      "age": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "billy",
      "age": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've found that `.dog[1]` will return me the first object but not in the `dog:[]` array.

```json
{
  "name": "billy",
  "age": "5"
}
```

and `.[] |= .[$i]` gives me an object:

```json
{
  "dog": {
    "name": "billy",
    "age": "5"
  }
}
```

What I want is:

```json
{
  "dog": [
    {
      "name": "sam",
      "age": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I plan to use this in a bash script, and write out to multiple files like:

`jq -r --argjson i "$i" '.[] |= .[$i]' "$1"`

Comment: Do you need the array slice?  .[1:2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jq --argjson i 2 '.dog|=[.[$i-1]]'
```

The `.dog|=[.[$index]]` part modifies just the array `dog` and replaces it with an array of just the item at position `$index`. This has the benefit of preserving anything else that might be in the top-level object. We use `$i-1` since you indicate you want to provide 1-based indices as input.

Comment: I had wondered about that. As it was already in dog that seems more efficient, rather than re-creating dog. As it's being used in a bash script, the counter is already initialized to 0, so `jq --argjson i 1 '.dog|=[.[$i]]'` will work nicely too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an integer index, use a slice. (Also, the array is 0-indexed, not 1-indexed.)

```
$ jq --argjson i 0 '{dog: .dog[$i:$i+1]}' < tmp.json
{
  "dog": [
    {
      "name": "sam",
      "age": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you are asking for an object, not a string, the `-r` option doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

JSON arrays starts from zero. you should use index 0 instead of 1:
`.dog[0]`

Comment: I know JSON originated in Javascript, but there's no reason to mention it here. Arrays in JSON (like in *many* languages) are zero-indexed.

Comment: @chepner I did adress js since it's a javascript object notation but you're correct, jq is for parsing JSON, and the question is not related to js. fixed :)

Comment: Regardless, this doeesn't answer at least half of the question - how to keep the structure of the input.

Comment: @Weeble He had the correct structure, his only issue was the indexing.